# PowerShell: Export Data from Specific Row Number from multiple files and export to one csv

Tags: powershell

Beginner user...

I have 30+ .dat files in one folder and need to export row 10 from each file and compile into one csv file.

I know I am on the right lines but am not sure of the middle section - this is where I'm at...

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\pitters\Folder\* -Include *.dat -Recurse
    ForEach-Object { 
    Select-Object -Skip 9 -First 1 } 
    Export-CSV -Path Users\pitters\Folder\output.csv
```

Am I missing Get-Content and can anyone help with what needs correcting?

Thanks in advance.
Matt

Comment: Which columns are you expecting in the resulting CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself, you need to invoke `Get-Content` to actually read the file contents. In addition, you also need to construct an object with appropriate properties corresponding to the coumns you want in your CSV file - something we can do with `Select-Object` directly:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\pitters\Folder\* -Include *.dat -Recurse |ForEach-Object { 
    $file = $_
    $file |Get-Content |Select-Object @{Name='Line10';Expression={$_}},@{Name='File';Expression={$file.FullName}} -Skip 9 -First 1 
} |Export-CSV -Path Users\pitters\Folder\output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks - getting the following Response: **'Export-CSV : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\pitters\Folder\Users\pitters\Folder\output.csv'.
At C:\Users\pitters\Documents\Get Content.ps1:12 char:4
+ } |Export-CSV -Path Users\pitters\Folder\output.csv
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand'**

Comment: Sounds like you're not currently in `C:` - Try changing the path to `C:\Users\pitters\Folder\output.csv`

Comment: @Pitmo Excellent! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)

Comment: Done - I did look for something like that but failed to see it :-)